# Is possible transform an analytic map into a monomial?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, coordinate-systems, analytic-functions

I'm quite new with the concept of a monomialization of a map, which seems to be quite useful. I'm hoping that, given a map with analytic coordinates $\boldsymbol{c}:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^p$ and a point $\boldsymbol{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, a monomialization is able of provide a continuously-differentiable surjective map $\phi: U \rightarrow V$  from an open set $U\subset \mathbb{R}^s$ to an open set $V\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ with $\phi(\boldsymbol{0}) = \boldsymbol{x}$ such that each coordinate of $\boldsymbol{c} \circ \phi$ is a monomial of degree bigger than 2. Is it possible?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by monomialization? Can you provide your definition? Secondly, there are obvious restrictions on being able to get the result you want: if $p>n$ or $c$ lands in some smaller-dimensional subvariety, what you want can't happen.

Comment: Ok! I will get rid of the term monomialization, 'cos it resemble some of other concepts in algebraic geometry. My monomialization is just transform a map into a monomial in each coordiate by right function compositions of diferentiable maps.

Comment: I'm not saying you are misusing the term or anything, I just want to know exactly what your definition is - if I start writing an answer and it turns out that we're using different definitions, then I've wasted both our time and I'd rather avoid that!

Comment: Let me know if things got better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, or almost. Each coordinate having a degree 2 or bigger is not necessarily possible, at least there are no well known theorems about it, as far I have looked on the internet. The [$\textbf{Theorem 2.1}$](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1990-317-02/S0002-9947-1990-0943608-5/) and introduction states what is possible to accomplish in my context. I hope it helps people in future.